# Is there a name for the property of a code where symbol "space" is left unused?

Tags: coding-theory, information-theory

For example, say I have the symbols A, B, C and D.

If I encode these as A = 1, B = 01, C = 001 and D = 0001 (for a very simple example), I have a very simple prefix code. However, I know straight away that it cannot be optimal. Instead of using D = 0001, I could have used D = 000 and retained the prefix property.

The second case (A = 1, B = 01, C = 001 and D = 000) could potentially be a Huffman code and may be optimal (or may not) depending on the probabilities of the symbols A, B, C and D.

My question is, is there a name for the property that distinguishes this second case from the first, *not* assuming anything about whether the second code is optimal or not?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for the confusing title.

Comment: I don't know about codes, but the resulting Huffman binary tree is called "full" if every node either has two or zero children. And do you mean A = 1?

Comment: Yes, A = 1, thanks. I can't think how a code could be a valid Huffman code and not contain a "full" tree; but this does not imply that everything with a "full" binary tree is a Huffman code (otherwise you would have nailed it). I was also hoping the property would generalise beyond binary - which I guess this might, but I have yet to convince myself.

Comment: What I meant was that _any_ binary tree, regardless of how it came to be, is called full iff it has no nodes with a single child. The Huffman algorithm guarantees that a the resulting tree is full, yes.

Comment: Ah, yes. And yes, this is another way of saying what I am; the space is entirely used or the tree representation is full. I just thought there was a property (like the "prefix property"). I seem to remember it from my coding theory classes > 10 years ago, but my mind has been known to play tricks. It seems like there *should* be a property name for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems if all space is used, the code is called a complete code.
I don't know the main source of the definition but it was used here: [If Kraft's inequality holds with equality, the code in question is a complete code.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4288259/if-krafts-inequality-holds-with-equality-the-code-in-question-is-a-complete-co)

Comment: Wow, you raised the dead!